# prepareForSegue not working with a Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a View Controller with an activity indicator to get data from my database. Once all the data is fetched, this view will performSegueWithIdentifier and use prepareForSegue to pass the data to a TableViewController. The issue that I am experiencing is that if I add a Navigation Controller in between the view that fetches the data and the TableViewController getting the data prepareForSegue does not work, I don't see the data on the TableViewController. However, if I remove the Navigation Controller I get the data just fine. Below is my prepareForSegue method. I am embedding a Navigation Controller there in order to get the transition effect I want with this segue which should have the TableViewController slide in from the left with a push segue. Thanks

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "serviceView" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ServiceTableViewController {
            destination.firstName = self.firstName
            destination.lastName = self.lastName
            destination.email = self.email
            destination.streetAddress = self.streetAddress
            destination.aptOrSuite = self.aptOrSuite
            destination.state = self.state
            destination.city = self.city
            destination.zipcode = self.zipcode
            destination.phone = self.phone
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd have thought destinationViewController is now a UINavigationController and not a ServiceTableViewController, why not run it and look at segue.destinationViewController in the IDE to see what it is.

Comment: yes, thank you, I did verify in debug mode that the destination is now UINavigationController. However, of course now I get the error " value of type UINavigationController has no member firstName." How can I now pass the data from the UINavigationController to the TableViewController? Do I now need a UINavigatonController class?

Comment: You could get the navigation controller's children as an array let vcs = segue.destinationViewController.viewControllers. The first child should be your ServiceTabeViewController (it would be good practice to programmatically check the first child actually is a ServiceTableViewController and assert if not, this will catch any problems you get during development if you change your storyboard but forget to update the prepareForSegue code).

Comment: Is there a reason you are adding the navigation controller between those two, and not before the first view controller? If you don't want the navigation bar to be visible in the first view controller for example, that is easy to do even if its embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working like this now if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController {
                
                if let targetController = destination.topViewController as? ServiceTableViewController{
                    targetController.firstName = self.firstName

Comment: I embedded a Navigation controller there because the Show (push) segue with a navigation controller gets me the transition I want, where it slides from the left instead of from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

embed the view controller that fetches the data in a navigation controller not the table view controller, so both view controllers are in the navigation controller's stack of view controllers

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access the NavigationController, then the topViewController, casting topViewController as your destination NavigationController

```
let destinationNavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
let targetController = destinationNavigationController.topViewController as! serviceView 
targetController.firstName = self.firstName
```